# What features make a file format friendly to VCS?

Tags: xml, git, svn, version-control

I'm writing an application with an xml-based file format that stores a graph of objects. I don't have a previous version to support.

My users are likely to place the files under version control and (inevitably) sometimes hand-edit to solve merge conflicts. I'd like to minimize the chances of merge conflicts happening in the first place, make resolving them as pain-free as possible and minimise the chances of the file becoming corrupted after being edited.

I can add specific information about the data I'm storing if needed, but what general principles should I keep in mind?

A few ideas I've had already:

- Being text-based (obviously)
- Ensuring that the same graph of objects is always represented in the same way
- Minimizing the number of relationships stored

Answer (score 2):

I think after the first two items you mention, the most important thing is probably to make sure you don't put too much information on a single line. Most version control systems track and merge changes in terms of lines, so if a lot of information is contained in a single line, then people changing very different things might end up modifying the same line and therefore generating a conflict. And these conflicts will be hard because most merge tools only support grabbing whole lines or whole hunks in a diff.

In other words: use line breaks liberally. It would be better to have too many than too few.

Another consideration is to avoid things like timestamps, hashes, etc. stored in the text as much as possible. I.e., avoid things that will change with every edit and in unpredictable ways. These will be hard or impossible to merge by hand.